# TaskCompletionSource cancellation with CancellationTokenSource does not update Task.Status?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

This seems unintuitive to me:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.Cancel();
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
try
{
    tcs.Task.Wait(cts.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(tcs.Task.Status); //TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation
}
```

I'd expect it to update the status to `TaskStatus.Canceled`. What is the rationale behind leaving it in `TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding `Wait()`.

`Wait(CancellationToken)` allows you to cancel the *wait* operation.
It has no effect on the underlying task.